# How to get Dynamic zones like functionality (strapi) in Directus? They say we can impliment using there newer Many-To-Any

Tags: node.js, strapi, directus, headless-cms, jamstack

so I'm using directus as my new backend as strapi has gotten buggy over the time and it's slower. Few things I miss from strapi are Dynamic Components/Zone

Example- We have 3 components A (title) - B (Image) - C (Markdown)

On one page/post I want the sequence of A/C/B while on the other B/A/C.
In strapi it was achieve able but in directus they say we can achieve same kind  of functionality using their Many to Any relationship type.

Any demonstration on how to achieve it?